# Very frequent log entries of gnome-software

Tags: gnome, syslog, gnome-software

Every 5 seconds or so, gnome-software writes something like that in the syslog:

```
Dec  3 09:11:23 xxxx gnome-software[5095]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Dec  3 09:11:23 xxxx gnome-software[5095]: hiding category productivity featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
Dec  3 09:11:23 xxxx gnome-software[5095]: hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
Dec  3 09:11:23 xxxx gnome-software[5095]: Only 8 apps for popular list, hiding
Dec  3 09:11:23 xxxx gnome-software[5095]: failed to call gs_plugin_add_installed on snap: Unable to connect snapd socket: Every 5 seconds or so, gnome-software writes something like that in the syslog:
```

My concern is not only to identify the source of messages (by instance, I know the last one comes from snapd service that is disabled) but mainly avoid those writings every 5 seconds or less, sometimes.

Please, how can I control the gnome-software logging behaviour?
Or, how can I change the schedule of this gnome-software checkings?

Many thanks.

Comment: Anybody can reproduce the same silly behaviour?

Comment: Every few seconds a lot of lines like `gnome-software: hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 1 to show, need at least 9` (or similar) is written to syslog... Every day thousands of useless bytes written in the system log ...

Comment: I've temporarily "solved" the problem via blocklist file in rsyslog ... but it's just a bad workaround